# Attempting to write Powershell script with nested ElseIf Statements. Script is not performing as anticipated

Tags: powershell, shell

I want to preface by stating that I am not the most versed in Powershell scripting.
I have written a script that uses the system date function to determine what drives to copy my downloads folder to based on the system date.  While the script partly works, **it only successfully copies the D drive and the E drive *regardless of system date***.

It's as if the other drives listed in the ElseIf statements aren't being read or considered.  I am curious if I may have my statements nested incorrectly or do not have enough brackets correctly inserted into the code as I am not very well versed in scripting Powershell statements.  I have also looked into potentially using a switch function if that is feasible for this kind of script and would provide better results.  Also it is four drives that will cycle on a five day week (Monday through Friday.)  That's why I have also included a weekend date variable into my powershell script.

Listed below is my current powershell script.

```
$TodaysDate = [DateTime]::Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$YesterdaysDate = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$WeekendDate = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

If ("D:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $YesterdaysDate" -Or "D:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $WeekendDate")
{
    md "E:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $TodaysDate"
    XCOPY   "C:\Users\daniel presnell\Downloads"  "E:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $TodaysDate"
}
ElseIf ("E:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $YesterdaysDate" -Or "E:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $WeekendDate")
{
    md "F:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $TodaysDate"
    XCOPY   "C:\Users\daniel presnell\Downloads" "F:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $TodaysDate"
}
ElseIf ("F:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $YesterdaysDate" -Or "F:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $WeekendDate")
{
    md "G:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $TodaysDate"
    XCOPY   "C:\Users\daniel presnell\Downloads" "G:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $TodaysDate"
}
ElseIf ("G:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $YesterdaysDate" -Or "G:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $WeekendDate")
{
    md "D:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $TodaysDate"
    XCOPY   "C:\Users\daniel presnell\Downloads" "D:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $TodaysDate"
}

ECHO Backup Complete!
```

Upon running this script D:\ and E:\ will successfully run based on the system date, but the other drives (F:\ and G:\ ) Will not run or function correctly.  The backups will not perform on weekend days hence the weekend date variable being added.  Would a switch function be more feasible for this purpose?  Are my statements nested correctly?  Thank you very much for your time and consideration into reviewing this matter.

Comment: Are the F & G drives mapped? Check File explorer to see if the machine has the drives..

Answer (score 2):

Any non-empty string in PowerShell is considered *truthy*, which means that your if and elseif conditions are *all true*, all the time.

You can observe this in an interactive shell by using the `-or` operator with any two string operands, as long as at least one of them is non-empty:

```
PS ~> "literally anything" -or ""
True
```

In order to test whether a given string is a resolvable path, use the `Test-Path` cmdlet:

```
If ((Test-Path "D:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $YesterdaysDate") -Or (Test-Path "D:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $WeekendDate"))
{
    md "E:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $TodaysDate"
    XCOPY   "C:\Users\daniel presnell\Downloads"  "E:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $TodaysDate"
}
```

`Test-Path` will return `$false` if the path does not resolve to an actual file system item.

Repeat for the else-if conditions

---

I also feel obliged to point out that your code can be simplified, vastly, since you're basically just repeating yourself with different drive letters:

```
# These date strings remain the same as before
$TodaysDate = [DateTime]::Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$YesterdaysDate = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$WeekendDate = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

# Now let's define a list of possible existing drives and the next target drives
$driveLetters = 'D E F G'.Split()

# now we just repeat the same operation for each drive and backup to the next drive in the list:
for($i = 0; $i -lt $driveLetters.Count; $i++){
  $testDrive = $driveLetters[$i]
  $targetDrive = $driveLetters[($i + 1) % $driveLetters.Count]

  if((Test-Path "${testDrive}:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $YesterdaysDate") -or (Test-Path "${testDrive}:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $WeekendDate"))
  {
    $newDirPath = "${targetDrive}:\SNAProBackupTest\backups $TodaysDate"
    md $newDirPath
    xcopy "C:\Users\daniel presnell\Downloads" $newDirPath

    # our work here is done, break out of loop
    break
  }
}

Write-Output 'Backup Complete!'
```

The `$driveLetters[($i + 1) % $driveLetters.Count]` statement ensures that we "wrap around" when we reach the end of the list, so that `G` maps back to `D`

Comment: Instead of using all the `ElseIf` it might be more efficient to use `Switch`

Comment: @Scepticalist I was just in the middle of updating the answer to show a better approach :)

Comment: MathiasR.Jessen Thank you very much!  I wasn't aware that there was a Test-Path cmdlet.  As stated by @Scepticalist I will also try to utilize the Switch function rather than the ElseIf.  Thank you so much for the clarification!

Comment: @dpresnell90 I don't think a `switch` is a good choice here, I'd definitely prefer a simple loop with an `if` statement (see last half of my answer) :)